# How to Read all Meeting request going through Organisation Exchange Server

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am developing a sample c# application which monitors all meeting request going through a organisation exchange server. I have tried to read all mails from a particular email address using EWS,

```
MailServer oServer = new MailServer("outlook.office365.com", 
                        "test@emailarchitect.net", "testpassword", ServerProtocol.ExchangeEWS );
            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

            // If your POP3 server requires SSL connection,
            // Please add the following codes:
            // oServer.SSLConnection = true;

            try
            {
                oClient.Connect(oServer);
                MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                {
                    MailInfo info = infos[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                        info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                    // Receive email from mail server
                    Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                    Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);
                }......
```

but the above code only reads mail from a particular mail address. I need to read all meeting request going through a particular organisation exchange server(Eg: form contoso.com domain )
Is it possible with EWS, or is there any other solution available.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the code you provide use EWS? It doesn't seem to be. How is this code related to your question? In the code you provide you are connecting to POP3 server. EWS only works on exchange servers.

Comment: Post Updated...Current i am using this code snippet to read inbox mails for a particular mail address. Is there any other solution to read all mails (mostly meeting request) from an organisation mail server(instead of giving single user mail address in an organisation domain).

Comment: What is the name of the API that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you consider using a Transport Agent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204097(v=exchg.150).aspx , Transport Agents will let you process the meeting invitations while they are in the Transport Pipeline. You should then be able to use the ical reader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.contenttypes.icalendar(v=exchg.150).aspx or parse the TNEF property on the message using the TNEF reader. There's a sample icalendar agent http://blogs.technet.com/b/jasoning/archive/2011/08/17/icalendar-property-rewrite.aspx

Cheers
Glen